# Print BinaryString without padding

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, complement

Suppose I have defined a `long` variable like this :

```
    long lng = 2543697L;
```

and print it out :

```
    System.out.println (" first long "+Long.toBinaryString(lng));
```

the output is this :

```
1001101101000001010001
```

but when I complement the bits using `~` a lots of leading `1's` appear  :

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111110110010010111110101110
```

and that makes sense (padding). Now my questions are :

**1. Why do these leading `1's appear in negation but not in original?**

**2. What should I do if I do not want to print them but just the complemented original bits only?**

Comment: They were leading zeroes in the original, so they didn't have to be printed.

Comment: @harold oops !! well , obviously that makes sense :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The 1's appear in the negated version because that's how the [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) binary representation for negative numbers works: `-x = ~x + 1`
2. If you want to limit the number of bits printed, I'd just count the number of bits used in the first number and only print that many bits from the second. [`Long.numberOfLeadingZeros`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#numberOfLeadingZeros%28long%29) could be helpful here:

   ```
   Long.toBinaryString(~lng).substring(Long.numberOfLeadingZeros(lng))
   ```

Comment: +1 Oh!! that's wonderful, that seems to be working, thanks !! Its probably my lack of knowledge of proper methods. I beg pardon for another question out of topic ,actually I am new in java and there seem to be a flurry of methods and classes , How can one get hold of each?

Comment: @PHI - Reading other peoples' code helps. Just looking through the JavaDocs can help too. A lot of times you can just do a search like ["java find highest order bit"](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+find+highest+order+bit) and you'll find someone else already asked a similar question on stackoverflow and received some great answers!

Answer (score 0):

The leading 1s are significant, if you remove them you will change the number:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111110110010010111110101110 != 10110010010111110101110
```